# Chrome Command Line Flags Do Nothing

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

I am attempting to launch chrome.exe with a few command line flags and am unable to do so. Whenever I launch it, the flags appear to be ignored and it just opens a vanilla Chrome instance.

Tested:

```
# Should open a very small window 
./chrome.exe --window-size=200,200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome must be fully closed before attempting to open it with command line flags. When you already have an instance of Chrome running, it merely opens a new window and ignores the flags from the command line.