# Chrome ignores command line parameters on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

When I run Google Chrome 120.0.6099.225 from the command line in Windows 10 22H2, e.g.

```
PS C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application> .\chrome.exe --help
```

or

```
PS C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application> .\chrome.exe --version
```

the command line parameters are ignored and Chrome opens a window, instead of displaying help information or its version.

I read that [command line parameters are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226698/chrome-command-line-flags-do-nothing) when Chrome has already opened a window (and I don't understand the rationale for that). But this happens without any open Chrome windows and without any `chrome.exe` processes, according to the Task Manager. I even tried this right after a restart with the same result.

How can I get Chrome to properly process the command line arguments? And if possible even dot that if there already is an open Chrome window (because `flutter doctor` expects a reply to `chrome --version`).

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to not check the version of the chrome.exe file

On another forum, they say to put google-chrome --version.

i am not sure if answers your question, but happy too help if i did.